# Sorting Python list by length of items' sub-property

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list called `agents` containing `Agent` objects.  Each object has a `solved` property which is a list, for example:

```
Agent.solved = [300, 50, 100, 7]
```

The length of each list is different.  I want to print results like this but I want the output ordered by the length of the `solved` property. How can I sort it that way?

```
for _id, obj in agents.items():
  print(obj, 'solved', len(obj), 'tickets')
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, could you post your attempt?

Comment: `for agent in sorted(agents, key=lambda x: len(x.solved))..` ?

Comment: I thought you said, `agents` was a `list` ?